# Can I change the "visited" color for just one or two links on my page?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'd like to change the visited color for just two of the links on my page. Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: why not putting your custom class to <a> element like `<a class="changeable">name</a>` and then alter it in css

Comment: This is a only a CSS question, so please consider retagging your question.

Comment: This is borderline for being flagged as "too basic"

Comment: @watson because the basics are explained in manuals and tutorials. On a Q&A site they yield catastrophic signal-to-noise ratios, IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a class on just the links that you want a different visited color for, for example:

```
<a class="different">Different</a>
```

In CSS then style that class of link that has been visited in whatever way you want, for example:

```
.different:visited {color:chartreuse;}
```

This uses the [:visited pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3avisited) to style only visited links.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to do this. Give those two links a special CSS class, then use the `:visited` selector as normal. In this example, I'll call it `.special`.

```
<a href="...">Link one</a>
<a href="..." class="special">Link two</a>
```

Then, in your stylesheet:

```
a:visited {
    color: purple;
}

a.special:visited {
    color: pink;
}
```

"Link one" will, when visited, appear in purple. Link two, when visited, will appear in pink.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want or can't add class to your anchor tags as @Adam suggested:

```
a[href='https://www.google.com/']:visited { color:#FF0000; }
a[href='https://www.facebook.com/']:visited { color:#0000FF; }
```